# PHP: Array Segregation

Tags: php, arrays

I have this string:

```
type=openBook&bookid=&guid=7AD92237-D3C7-CD3E-C052-019E1EBC16B8&authorid=&uclass=2&view=
```

Then I want to get all the values after the "=" sign so for the "type" i want to get "openBook" and put this in an array.

Note: even if it is null it must be added to the array so i wont loose track..

So how can i do that.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want [`parse_str`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```
<?php
$str = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz";
parse_str($str);
echo $first;  // value
echo $arr[0]; // foo bar
echo $arr[1]; // baz

parse_str($str, $output);
echo $output['first'];  // value
echo $output['arr'][0]; // foo bar
echo $output['arr'][1]; // baz
?>
```

I'm not sure what you mean by this bit:

> Note: even if it is null it must be
>   added to the array so i wont loose
>   track..

If `parse_str` doesn't work quite as you want post a comment and I'll try and help.

Comment: +1. I think he wanted to have `type` included in the array even when it is not defined (or empty?) in the string.

Comment: ow sorry about that what i meant was. if type="" it must also store a null or empty value to the array

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look to explode();

```
<?php

$foo = "type=openBook&bookid=&guid=7AD92237-D3C7-CD3E-C052-019E1EBC16B8&authorid=&uclass=2&view=";

$chuncks = explode('&', $foo);

$data = array();

foreach ($chuncks as $chunck)
{
  $bar = explode('=', $chunck);
  $data[$bar[0]] = $bar[1];

}

var_dump($data);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$first = split("&", "type=openBook&bookid=&guid=7AD92237-D3C7-CD3E-C052-019E1EBC16B8&authorid=&uclass=2&view=");

foreach($first as $value) {
    list($key, $val) = split("=", $value);
    $arr[$key] = $val;
}

echo $arr['type'];    // openBook
```

Comment: explode() would be better than split(). First, you don't use regular expression, second - split is deprecated since 5.3